# Spring Boot + JWT + Kotlin: login URL 403

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin, jwt

Followed this article: https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-kotlin/

Doing a home grown auth, the second part of the article.

When I try to POST to the login URL, i get a 403 error.

Here is my `SignUpController`:

```
package io.bss.api.controller

import io.bss.api.model.User
import io.bss.api.repository.UserRepository
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sign-up")
class SignUpController(val userRepository: UserRepository, val bCryptPasswordEncoder: BCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    @PostMapping()
    fun signUp(@RequestBody user: User) {
        user.password = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.password)
        userRepository.save(user)
    }
}
```

And my web security class:

```
package io.bss.api.security

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class WebSecurity(val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Bean
    fun bCryptPasswordEncoder(): BCryptPasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
    }

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder?) {
        auth!!.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder())
    }
}
```

I see that the article was written back in June of 2017, so perhaps something in spring boot changed? This is my first time using it, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: Please, try to declare `RestController` instead of `Controller`

Comment: that worked :) please submit as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Now i get a 403 when i try to hit the /login URL

Comment: I've answered, thanks. And your 403 is completely another trouble. I think that you should allow anonymous users to view `/login` page or even completely ignore it in security (`.ignore()`)

Comment: the 403 ended up being the security system expecting a username field to exist, but my user object didn't have one.

Comment: I think you should create the separate question for this trouble (if you didn't solve this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you're trying touse `@Controller` annotation while using REST.

You have 2 options here:

1. Annotate your class as `@RestController`
2. Annotate each method in your controller with `@ResponseBody`, but you will need to return something then.